# Compilation issues on blackberry java plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, compilation

I'm writing an application for blackberry OS 5 with the Blackberry Java Plug-in 1.1.1 on Eclipse 3.5 and Windows 7 x64. My application consists of five projects 2 libs and 3 applications. When i compile the libraries everything goes well, but when i try to package any of the three apps the following happens:

1 - First time the resulting cod files are useless. When i install any of these cods on the simulator or a device nothing happens.

2 - At this moment i realized that if i make a change on one of the three packages causing the recompilation to deliver new cods, the size of the new cods are bigger, they do work fine. If i repeat this i go back to step one, so i have to compile the three projects twice every time.

This situation is very odd and time consuming. Any idea on what could be the problem?  Thanks in advance and I’m sorry for my English.

Comment: run clean.batch file situated at \Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I've allready cleaned the simulator several times with the clean.bat file and still same result. The libraries are packages on my workspace so in the end they are cod files to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest upgrading to the latest versions of Eclipse (currently Indigo 3.7) and the BlackBerry plugin (currently 1.5), there have been a lot of bug fixes over the past year which may solve your issues.

Secondly, have you considered including your library source code directly into your app by adding them to the project build path? I have found this to be a much more reliable way of including library code into a BlackBerry project, and it saves messing around with multiple library cods.